# Dynamics AX 2009: How to sort an unbound form control's contents?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

I was using a **Listbox** control on a form, and programmatically adding **items** to it. I thought that if I called the *sort(SortOrder::Ascending)* method on the **Listbox** it would do just that -- however, I was wrong.

Ultimately, I am unable to achieve these results. I don't have to use a **Listbox**, but I need two pieces of functionality:

1. Programmatically be able to add Strings to the control
2. Be able to run code when an item is *clicked* or *selected*
3. The list should be able to be sorted alphabetically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't get the listbox to sort either.  Easiest might be to use a "ListView" control instead of a listbox.  You can see how to use AND sort in (AOT>Forms\tutorial_Form_ListControl).  Your requirements #1 & #2 are possible on almost anything you do.  The issue is sorting I'd think.

Another option, keep a local variable that controls the sorting.  I would use a [collection class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa608508.aspx), either an Array or Map so you can control the sorting via key-value, then you could just re-load the listbox when the user added/removed something.  Since it's client side and it doesn't sound like the listbox will have 1000+ controls, re-loading it probably won't be a significant performance hit.  You can also use listbox.insert([value], [index]), to insert into the correct location if you are controlling properly.

Another option, hi-jack any simple table from the AOT (TmpABC is a good one), insert the values, then sort using a simple query or even better, set the TmpABC to the ListView control's datasource and just sort via datasource sort..

Comment: Ultimately I went with a ListView, but I can't seem to get it looking right. I wanted a single column, with many rows and a _vertical_ scrollbar, but instead I get many columns, fixed number of rows and a _horizontal_ scrollbar.  At least it works, and is alphabetically sorted!

Comment: Glad it's working some at least.  I've not played with ListView at all, so I would have to see your specific issue to try and figure it out.  The TmpABC idea sounds odd, but it'd work great if you used it.  Just reload the listbox after each insert/delete.

Comment: There won't be any inserts/deletes.  This is a list of static data that will NOT change while the user is looking at it.  Essentially, it's a list of Security Keys, and when you click on a named key, the Infolog pops up which groups have access and what type of access.

Comment: Oh that's easy then, just sort the list before you fill the listbox if you want to use that control.  Fill the temp table with the data, then just select * from the table and order by, then while looping fill the listbox.

Comment: Yeah, the problem there is that the only way to get a list of the Security Keys (complete list) is to use a class, because they are kernel protected items. The table AccessRightsList contains a listing of which groups can access which keys (by id only). If a key hasn't been assigned to anything yet, it doesn't appear in the table at all. The ListView is still working, because it has a property -- *Sort* with a value set to *Ascending*. :-) Thanks, though, Alex K!